# How do I model an order relation in core.logic?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I'm trying to model an order relation between a finite set of tasks using core logic. This is what I have so far:

```
(def tasks [:t0 :t1 :t2])

(defn tasko [x]
    (membero x tasks))

(db-rel before-fact x y)
(def facts 
  (db 
    [before-fact :t0 :t1]
    [before-fact :t1 :t2]))

(defn before [x y]
  (conde
    [(before-fact x y)]
    [(fresh [z]
      (tasko z)
      (before x z)
      (before z y))]))

(defn after [x y]
  (before y x))
```

And I run this query:

```
(with-db facts 
  (run 3 [q] ; If run with 2, result is correct
    (after q :t0)))
```

The objective is to only specify immediate order relations in the database (as in, 1<2, 2<3, 3<4 but not 1<3 or 2<4) and let the system infer those from the transitivity of goal "before" combined with the "after" goal.

My code works fine if I ask for 2 or less values, but once I ask for a 3rd one (at this point execution should stop because there are no more values to try) the program hangs.

Why is it hanging at this point? I'm pretty sure it's the recursion step defined in the before goal, but I'm not sure on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You are *so* close! You are right about the problem being in the recursion step of the before goal. Change `(before x z)` to `(before-fact x z)` and it should work.

In the version you provide, there are no statements to ground the value of `z` with relation to `x` or `y`, so the program is left to check the same values over and over and over...